# how to convert unix time to unix date by moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, unix, timestamp, momentjs

Some string like 1487152419798 its a timestamp with date & time
i need string like 1487152419798 a timestamp with date & 00:00.

```
let timestamp = '1487152419798';
let date = moment(Number(timestamp)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
let unixDate = moment.unix(date);  //don't work
```

i need 2017.02.15 00:00 in unix

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. What end result do you want from that number?

Comment: @t-j-crowder, 2017.02.17 00:00 in unix

Comment: "in unix" is meaningless in that sentence. In local time? UTC? Also, depending on  your timezone, 1487152419798 is either Feb 14th, 15th, or 16th, but certainly not the 17th.

Comment: @t-j-crowder, i need sort (group) timestamps by day

Comment: const unixDate = moment(date).unix();
console.log(moment(unixDate * 1000).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

Comment: Again: UTC or local time?

Comment: @YuraZatsepin, выводит 1970-01-18

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok let it be local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `startOf("day")` to modify a Moment instance to set all time fields to 0. So first convert `timestamp` to a number:

```
timestamp = Number(timestamp)
```

and then either:

If you want local:

```
let local = moment(timestamp).startOf("day");
```

or if you want UTC:

```
let utc = moment.utc(timestamp).startOf("day");
// Note---------^^^^^
```

```js
let timestamp = Number('1487152419798');
let local = moment(timestamp).startOf("day");
let utc = moment.utc(timestamp).startOf("day");
console.log("Date in local timezone: ", local.format());
console.log("Date in UTC: ", utc.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let timestamp = '1487152419798';
let date = new Date(Number(timestamp));
```

`date` should give you the required value.